# Building an animated menu with Jquery that responds to page scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, navigation, scroll

Sorry for the terrible title, but I'm not sure how else to describe what I'm trying to build. I'm using some code I found on this site, basically what I'm trying to do is build a left handed navigation menu, that highlights the appropriate section as the user scrolls to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var topRange = 200, // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
    edgeMargin = 20, // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
    animationTime = 600, // time in milliseconds
    contentTop = []; //array of sidebar links
  $('nav ul').append('<div id="slider"></div>');

  var sliderTop = $("nav ul li a").eq(0).parent().position().top;
  var sliderLeft = $("nav ul li a").eq(0).parent().position().left;
  var sliderHeight = $("nav ul li a").eq(0).parent().outerHeight();

  $('#slider').css({
    'height': sliderHeight,
    'left': sliderLeft,
    'top': sliderTop,
    'width': '100%'
  });


  // Stop animated scroll if the user does something
  $('html,body').bind('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which > 0 || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mousewheel') {
      $('html,body').stop();
    }
  })

  // Set up content an array of locations
  $('#sidebar').find('a').each(function() {
    contentTop.push($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
  })

  // Animate menu scroll to content
  $('#sidebar').find('a').click(function() {
    var sel = this,
      newTop = Math.min(contentTop[$('#sidebar a').index($(this))], $(document).height() - $(window).height()); // get content top or top position if at the document bottom
    $('html,body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': newTop
    }, animationTime, function() {
      window.location.hash = $(sel).attr('href');
    });
    return false;
  })

  //scroll function
  function scroller() {
      var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        bodyHt = $(document).height(),
        vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin; // viewport height + margin
      $.each(contentTop, function(i, loc) {
        if ((loc > winTop - edgeMargin && (loc < winTop + topRange || (winTop + vpHt) >= bodyHt))) {

          //animate slider
          x = $("#sidebar li").eq(i).position();
          $("#slider").animate({
            top: (x.top)
          }, 100);
        }
      })
    }
    //scroll event handler
  $(window).scroll(scroller)
})
```

I have most of it working, however when you actually click a link on the menu the animation is very slow to catch up with the actual scrolling. I understand why this is happening, because it updates the position one at a time after each section is reached, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make this animation faster, and more fluid. I've attached a fiddle with my code, thank you in advance for your help!

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesmyers/6mbmq1pe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a better slider animation effect by temporarily detaching the `scroll` handler and scrolling the slider directly, with the same `animationTime` as for the main animation.

To do this, you also need to :

- namespace the scroll event `.nav`, to allow safe use of `.off()`
- `stop()` the slider animation in the "if the user does something" block

I've also included a few efficiency savings in the way `contentTop` and `#slider` are set up but these are not actually necessary.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var topRange = 200, // measure from the top of the viewport to X pixels down
        edgeMargin = 20, // margin above the top or margin from the end of the page
        animationTime = 600, // time in milliseconds
        contentTop, //array of sidebar links
        navLinkWrapper = $("nav ul li a").eq(0).parent();

    var $slider = $("<div id=\"slider\" />").css({
        'height': navLinkWrapper.outerHeight(),
        'left': navLinkWrapper.position().left,
        'top': navLinkWrapper.position().top,
        'width': '100%'
    }).appendTo($('nav ul'));

    // Stop animated scroll if the user does something
    $('html,body').on('scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which > 0 || e.type == 'mousedown' || e.type == 'mousewheel') {
            $('html,body').stop();
            $slider.stop(); //<<<<<<<
        }
    });

    // Set up content an array of locations
    contentTop = $('#sidebar a').map(function() {
        return $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top;
    });

    // Animate menu scroll to content
    $('#sidebar a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(window).off('scroll.nav', scroller); //<<<<<<<
        $slider.stop().animate({ //<<<<<<<
            top: ($(this).closest("li").position().top) //<<<<<<<
        }, animationTime); //<<<<<<<
        var sel = this,
            newTop = Math.min(contentTop[$('#sidebar a').index($(this))], $(document).height() - $(window).height()); // get content top or top position if at the document bottom
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': newTop
        }, animationTime, function() {
            window.location.hash = $(sel).attr('href');
            $(window).on('scroll.nav', scroller); //<<<<<<<
        });
    });

    //scroll function
    function scroller() {
        var winTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
            bodyHt = $(document).height(),
            vpHt = $(window).height() + edgeMargin; // viewport height + margin
        $.each(contentTop, function(i, loc) {
            if ((loc > winTop - edgeMargin && (loc < winTop + topRange || (winTop + vpHt) >= bodyHt))) {
                //animate slider
                $slider.animate({
                    top: ($("#sidebar li").eq(i).position().top)
                }, 100);
            }
        });
    }
    //scroll event handler
    $(window).on('scroll.nav', scroller); //<<<<<<<
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6mbmq1pe/2/)**

Comment: Thanks so much! That works great, I really appreciate it. Thanks for clearly marking your changes as well, it really helps me learn. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but I noticed after these changes were added that sometimes when scrolling the slider falls behind. Is there anything I can do to correct that?

Comment: I'm not seeing that, but there's actually a worse issue in that the slider animation stops dead under "if the user does something" conditions. The solution is rather tricky - http://jsfiddle.net/6mbmq1pe/3/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I noticed that as well, even with your latest fiddle. Am I going about this the wrong way? Would there be an easier way of accomplishing this effect?

Comment: Quite possibly, though I think it's just a question of refinement. Keep working at it until you've ironed out the bugs.

Comment: Will do. Thanks again for your time,  I'll keep messing around with it.